# How do i GZIP static resources using zlib?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, gzip, zlib

Edit: I'm using Ruby with Sinatra.

UPDATE: here is the code I'm using which doesn't work...

```
get '/' do
    session[:time] = Time.now
    z = Zlib::Deflate.new(6, 31)
    z.deflate(File.read('public/Assets/Styles/build.css'))
    z.flush
    z.finish
    z.close
    erb :home
end
```

...I don't get any errors. But when I check the file via Firebug's Yslow plugin it tells me that file isn't GZIP'ed

I'm trying to understand how I GZIP web page content and static files like JavaScript and CSS using `zlib`?

I know I can pass a string of data to `Zlib::Deflate.deflate` but I'm using Sinatra with ERB files. So do I pass in a path to the ERB file and the Js/CSS files? Or can I pass in the directory where scripts/styles are stored? Would I pass in a path to the ERB file or the symbol that references the ERB file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are writing your own HTTP server, your server needs to handle this.  The client first has to let the server know that it accepts gzip content encoding, and then the server can deliver gzip content encoding.

Zlib::Deflate.deflate will not produce gzip-encoded data.  It will only produce zlib-encoded data.  You would need to use Zlib::Deflate.new with the windowBits argument equal to 31 to start a gzip stream.

Comment: OK, so I should use `z = Zlib::Deflate.new(1, 31)` and then after that I could use `z.deflate(File.read("path/to/file"))` would that be correct? 

Note the documentation isn't clear as to limit of 'level' argument so I've specified 1 but don't really know what the range I'm dealing with?

Comment: Yes.  The range is 1 to 9, with 6 being the default.  You should use something other than 6 only if you have throughput problems and need higher speed at the cost of lower compression (values less than 6), or if you don't care about speed and want to eek out that last little bit of compression (values more than 9).  You'll need to close the deflate stream as well to make sure it compresses the last bit it got.

Comment: @mark-adlert hi again, this didn't work for me. I've updated my question (see above) to show the code I'm using now but that doesn't appear to have worked to GZIP the content of the file?

Comment: that didn't work (see my updated question for latest code) - you'll see I'm using `flush`, `finish` and `close`.

Comment: So where are you expecting to get the result?  z.deflate(...), result = z.finish, or result = z.deflate(..., Zlib::FINISH) will put the gzip stream in result.